# iterate through array of hashes and output key, value

Tags: ruby

I'd like to do the following:

```
<% tags=[{"2":"birds"},{"3":"cars"}] %>

<% tags.each do |key, value| %>
   <%=key %> <%=value %>
<% end %>
```

but this doesn't work. How would I do this (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each hash can have any number of key/value pairs:

```
<% tags=[{"2":"birds"},{"3":"cars"}] %>

<% tags.each do |t| %>
   <% t.each do |key,value| %>
      <%=key %> <%=value %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```